# Reputable Rental Suppliers in the UK?

Tags: renting

In just over a week's time, I'm headed to the northernmost part of Norway, inside the Arctic Circle.

I'm hoping to see, and get some photographs of, the Aurora Borealis and to that end, I'd like to rent a decent wide angle lens.

Any recommendations for suppliers in the UK? I'm based in London, so somewhere with a storefront in the City would be ideal - but web based would work too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localised and would not apply to most users of Photography at Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whilst I've not used them personally, I've heard reasonable things about [Lenses For Hire](http://www.lensesforhire.co.uk/) - they don't offer a collection server, and you have to return to a courier depot though (read into that what you will).

**EDIT:**
Actually, they do offer collection, but it is not form their premises "for security reasons" - you would need to phone & discuss. They do also support returns to a mailbox/courier office, which can save courier fees.

Comment: I often rent from Lenses For Hire - I've found the service to be excellent. They don't have a store front, but you *can* arrange to collect in person in Maidenhead.

Answer (score 2):

Fixation are very reputable (I've sent lenses in for repair though I haven't personally rented anything from them) and they have a store in central London (Lambeth) they're generally not as cheap as lensesforhire but you save money by not having to courier the lenses. See http://www.fixationuk.com

Answer (score 2):

I have not used these guys, but I have been tempted (especially as they are based near me).
I believe you can collect or courier.

http://www.hireacamera.com/about/index.asp